# Quantile regression for non linear regression analysis?

Tags: linear, quantile-regression

I am new to quantile regression, I have read the original paper from Koenker and Bassett and also other documents.

I was under the impression that quantile regression is only used with linear regression functions, but after reading this I am confused:

https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2013/12/23/quantile-regression-robustness/

The author seems to imply that he can calculate quantile regression for any curve.

Is quantile regression also used with other types of functions other than linear?

Answer (score 4):

Unlike the answer from @Arne Jonas Warnke , I see no need to restrict attention to non-parametric estimators for nonlinear quantile regression.

Simply use whatever form of nonlinear function of the parameter vector $\beta$ , namely $f(\beta)$, you have in place of $X\beta$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression#Conditional_quantile_and_quantile_regression .  Of course, if $f(\beta)$ is a nonlinear function of the parameter vector $\beta$, the quantile regression problem will not be a Linear Programming problem, but it could still be solved with an appropriate nonlinear optimization solver.

Comment: Arne Jonas Warnke and Mark L.Stone, both of you helped me clarify my confusion, now I see where I was wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course, there are non-parametric estimator for quantile regression, see for example [Horrowitz and Lee (2004)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.532.3682&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

But I think there may be some confusion about the meaning of the term *linear*. See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/8706/9866) nice answer here at CrossValidated. The models in the [blog post](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2013/12/23/quantile-regression-robustness/) are indeed additive and linear.