# How do we use linear regression in which response variable is related to the regressors in a nonlinear fashion?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, linear-model, regression-coefficients

"This is called a multiple linear regression model because more than one regressor
is involved. The adjective linear is employed to indicate that the model is linear in
the parameters β 0 , β 1 , . . . , β k , not because y is a linear function of the x ’ s. We shall see subsequently that many models in which y is related to the x ’ s in a nonlinear
fashion can still be treated as linear regression models as long as the equation is
linear in the β ’ s.”

This is a quote from a text book. What I’m trying to understand is the last part, what does “ the equation is linear in the $\beta$’s” mean? In the same vein, how do we check if the equation is linear in the $\beta$’s?

Thank you!

Comment: For example. $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_1^2$ is linear in the $\beta$ terms because it can be rewritten as $y = \sum_{j = 0}^2 \beta_j x_j$ with just a little extra notation $x_0 := 1, x_2 := x_1^2$.

Comment: And then something like $y=\beta_0+\beta_1 \sin(\beta_2 x_1)$ is nonlinear, since there is no way to write that the way @NickCox wrote his equation as a sum.

Comment: @Dave: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: okay, so as long as the there’s one B to each regressor, then the equation is linear in the B’s, like you guys have shown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between linear equation and linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/470625/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-equation-and-linear-regression)

Comment: yes thank you @AdrianKeister also